# Full Disk Decryption via DHCP

Tags: dhcp, disk-encryption

I would like to implement full disk encryption on all clients. But to avoid having people to enter the FDE access code when they boot, I am wondering if the access code can be distributed by DHCP or similar.

The idea is that FDE should protect the laptop when it is stolen or outside the company, but if it is used on the company network we assume it is not stolen.

Ideally I would like the access code to be a one time access code, so if someone sniffs the DHCP answer, they will not be able to decrypt the laptop in general.

Comment: DNSSEC comes to my mind for an alternative protocol that allows for other data to be shipped with it. Neat idea BTW.

Comment: You could boot via pxe which contains the boot code (like initramfs) and the key to decrypt the storage. However I find it hard to do this without trusting the machine in some way. If someone has the capability to sniff the traffic (connected to your network), even with a one-time key what does stop him from just booting the machine while connected to your network? If the laptop is stolen and he has no access to your network then it might work.

Answer (score 2):

Since this will likely involve writing a Custom Initramfs, or at least a hook, you might find these resources interesting (ignore the Gentoo specific bits):

- https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Custom_Initramfs
- https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Custom_Initramfs#DHCP
- https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Custom_Initramfs/Examples#Self-Decrypting_Server

The Self-Decrypting Server example produces an encryption key like this:

```
( 
    # CPU:
    grep -vE '(MHz|bogomips)' /proc/cpuinfo
    # RAM:
    tail /proc/iomem
    # MAC-Address: (requires network drivers)
    cat /sys/class/net/*/address
    # Block devices and partitions (ignore optional CD drive):
    grep -v sr0 /proc/partitions
    # Random file:
    cat /root/secret
) | sha512sum | xargs echo -n > /root/key
```

That's supposed to protect against someone walking by your server and popping the hard disks out; the HDD by itself does not know the CPU, RAM, MAC-Address of the server so it can't decrypt itself outside of the box it belongs to.

In case of a laptop (where the entire device is stolen) this is not helpful as the thief would have all that data along with it, so you have to replace this with your DHCP data instead.

So after you obtained IP address and such via DHCP it could be something like:

```
(
    cat /sys/class/net/*/address
    ip addr show
    ip route show
    cat /etc/resolv.conf
) | sha512sum | xargs echo -n > /root/key
```

And that would give you a hash/passphrase based on your MAC address, the IP address and route, and DNS servers and such.

It would work as long as DHCP always sets the laptop up the same way, so DHCP server would have to remember the laptop configuration forever or the laptop will stop booting.

Such a solution is always a bit volatile so make sure to make use of LUKS supporting several passphrases, have a backup passphrase ready in case the DHCP one breaks.

It's also not very secure; this DHCP information is public (to the one using the laptop) and probably not hard to guess (for anyone using a different laptop in the same environment), so it will protect against the average thief but not the slightly tech savvy coworker-from-hell.